# MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch in ngnix docker container deployed to AWS ECS

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-config

Steps performed at glance:

- Angular 10 build step
- Nginx docker container build and push step
- AWS ECS service restart to refresh public container

Error received on endpoint:

```
GEThttp://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/runtime.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 71ms]

GEThttp://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/polyfills.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 55ms]

GEThttp://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/styles.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 67ms]

GEThttp://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/vendor.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 66ms]

GEThttp://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/main.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 105ms]

The resource from “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/polyfills.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/polyfills.js”. <aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>:12:1

The resource from “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/runtime.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/runtime.js”. <aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>:12:1

The resource from “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/styles.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/styles.js”. <aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>:12:1

The resource from “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/vendor.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/vendor.js”. <aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>:12:1

The resource from “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/main.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/main.js”. <aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>:12:1
GEThttp://<aws load balancer endpoint (masked)>/favicon.ico
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY mime.types /etc/nginx/mime.types
COPY security-headers.conf /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf
COPY /dist/payload-ng /usr/dist/nginx/html
```

nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes    1;
worker_rlimit_nofile    8192;

events {
  worker_connections    1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;  
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   128;
    sendfile    on; 
        
    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name localhost;
        root    /usr/dist/nginx/html;
        index   index.html;
        
        location / {
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
            add_header Cache-Control 'max-age=86400'; # one day
            include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf; 
        }

        location ~ .*\.css$|.*\.js$ {               
            add_header Cache-Control 'max-age=31449600'; # one year        
            include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf;        
        }

        location ~ /index.html|.*\.json$ {
            expires -1;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,
            proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        }
    }
}
```

mime.types:

types {

```
  # Data interchange

    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/json                      json map topojson;
    application/ld+json                   jsonld;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;
    application/vnd.geo+json              geojson;
    application/xml                       rdf xml;


  # JavaScript

    # Normalize to standard type.
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
    application/javascript                js;


  # Manifest files

    application/manifest+json             webmanifest;
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json   webapp;
    text/cache-manifest                   appcache;


  # Media files

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mp4                             aac f4a f4b m4a;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             oga ogg opus;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;
    audio/x-wav                           wav;
    image/bmp                             bmp;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    image/png                             png;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/webp                            webp;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp4                             f4v f4p m4v mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/ogg                             ogv;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;

    # Serving `.ico` image files with a different media type
    # prevents Internet Explorer from displaying then as images:
    # https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/commit/37b5fec090d00f38de64b591bcddcb205aadf8ee

    image/x-icon                          cur ico;


  # Microsoft Office

    application/msword                                                         doc;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                                                   xls;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                                              ppt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;


  # Web fonts

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/font-woff2                woff2;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;

    # Browsers usually ignore the font media types and simply sniff
    # the bytes to figure out the font type.
    # https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-a-font-type-pattern
    #
    # However, Blink and WebKit based browsers will show a warning
    # in the console if the following font types are served with any
    # other media types.

    application/x-font-ttf                ttc ttf;
    font/opentype                         otf;


  # Other

    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/octet-stream              bin deb dll dmg exe img iso msi msm msp safariextz;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-bb-appworld             bbaw;
    application/x-bittorrent              torrent;
    application/x-chrome-extension        crx;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-opera-extension         oex;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xslt+xml                  xsl;
    application/zip                       zip;
    text/css                              css;
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vcard                            vcard vcf;
    text/vnd.rim.location.xloc            xloc;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/vtt                              vtt;
    text/x-component                      htc;

}
```

security-headers.conf:

```
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header Feature-Policy "microphone 'none'; geolocation 'none'; camera 'none'" always;
```

At this point i am not sure what is the cause of getting the mime type error, double checked if the lates image is runing in ECS. Nginx is a new stack i am getting familiar with and lacking of oversight on this matter, and i would appreciate help with it. My best knowledge is it should serv the js files with the proper "text/javascript" header, but i can be easily wrong. I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you've seen is because, the actual file format is different from the file format you're referencing in your HTML or JS file.
Please refer to the link below to find out the correct MIME Type for your file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types

Then you should choose the correct MIME Type. For example,
if you are referencing CSS file, the MIME type should be 'text/css', if you are referencing the Javascript file, then it should be 'text/javascript'. Similarly, for HTML, 'text/HTML' and so forth.

If you use the correct MIME Type for your file, you can solve the issue.

Comment: it was the missing entry in the config as you pointed out. thank you